# Lumify: Accumulo-Securegraph-Lumify deploy using jetty?

Tags: visualization, sharding, graph-visualization, accumulo

I have followed all the steps in building and setting up lumify along with all the dependencies. However when trying to deploy the same in jetty, it fails to deploy with the following error.

```
2015-06-03 15:26:54.740:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.10.v20150310
2015-06-03 15:26:54.757:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/home/tanny/binaries/jetty-distribution-9.2.10.v20150310/webapps/] at interval 1
2015-06-03 15:27:04.315:INFO:l5.0-SNAPSHOT:main: Initializing AtmosphereFramework
Servlet context initialized...
2015-06-03 15:27:07.138/IST WARN  [hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader] Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-06-03 15:27:09.395:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2210a531{/lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-any-2282307658380437756.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war}
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:||1) Error injecting constructor, com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][0]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][0]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }{[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][1]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][1]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }{[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][2]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][2]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }{[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][3]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][3]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }{[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][4]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][4]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }|  at io.lumify.securegraph.model.ontology.SecureGraphOntologyRepository.<init>(SecureGraphOntologyRepository.java:68)|  at io.lumify.securegraph.model.ontology.SecureGraphOntologyRepository.class(SecureGraphOntologyRepository.java:40)|  while locating io.lumify.securegraph.model.ontology.SecureGraphOntologyRepository|  at io.lumify.core.bootstrap.LumifyBootstrap.configure(LumifyBootstrap.java:140)|  at io.lumify.core.bootstrap.LumifyBootstrap.configure(LumifyBootstrap.java:140)|  while locating io.lumify.core.model.ontology.OntologyRepository|    for parameter 3 at io.lumify.securegraph.model.user.SecureGraphUserRepository.<init>(SecureGraphUserRepository.java:60)|  at io.lumify.securegraph.model.user.SecureGraphUserRepository.class(SecureGraphUserRepository.java:39)|  while locating io.lumify.securegraph.model.user.SecureGraphUserRepository|  at io.lumify.core.bootstrap.LumifyBootstrap.configure(LumifyBootstrap.java:131)|  at io.lumify.core.bootstrap.LumifyBootstrap.configure(LumifyBootstrap.java:131)|  while locating io.lumify.core.model.user.UserRepository|    for parameter 0 at io.lumify.web.ApplicationBootstrap.setUserRepository(ApplicationBootstrap.java:107)|  while locating io.lumify.web.ApplicationBootstrap||1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwProvisionExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:451)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:944)
    at io.lumify.core.bootstrap.InjectHelper.inject(InjectHelper.java:33)
    at io.lumify.core.bootstrap.InjectHelper.inject(InjectHelper.java:25)
    at io.lumify.web.ApplicationBootstrap.setupInjector(ApplicationBootstrap.java:112)
    at io.lumify.web.ApplicationBootstrap.contextInitialized(ApplicationBootstrap.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
Caused by: 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][0]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][0]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }{[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][1]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][1]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }{[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][2]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][2]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }{[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][3]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][3]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }{[TtFQFvKBQgCqdBXe7OaHlw][securegraph][4]: SearchParseException[[securegraph][4]: from[0],size[10000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_child":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"authorizations":["ontology"]},{"term":{"http://lumify.io#conceptType_exactMatch":"concept"}}]}}}},"child_type":"property","score_type":"avg"}}}},"filter":{"and":{"filters":[{"terms":{"__elementType":["vertex"]}},{"authorizations":["ontology"]}]}}}},"functions":[{"script_score":{"script":"_score  * sqrt(     1    + (inEdgeMultiplier * doc['__inEdgeCount'].value)     + (outEdgeMultiplier * doc['__outEdgeCount'].value)    )","lang":"groovy","params":{"outEdgeMultiplier":1.1,"inEdgeMultiplier":1.2}}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[securegraph] No filter registered for [authorizations]]; }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing and what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Under:

> Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2210a531{/lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-any-2282307658380437756.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war}

It looks like it is looking for your lumify.properties file which should be in your lumify/config folder (if you are running this in docker, it is in /opt/lumify/config). Can you verify that it is there.

The other thing is the lumify.war file. 
I am not sure which instructions you followed, but can you verify that you did the following (starting from getting Lumify)

```
git clone the (lumify repository)

#prep webapp folder  
cd lumify/web/war/src/main/webapp

sudo npm install -g inherits bower grunt
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli

cd ~/lumify

#create the war file (I am going to assume you are running this in docker)
mvn clean package -P web-war -pl web/war -am -DskipTests -Dsource.skip=true

#change to the created war folder, you should see a file called lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war
cd web/war/target
ls -al

#Copy (and rename)the war file to the webapps folder used by jetty. It needs to be renamed root.war.
cp lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/ec2-user/lumify/docker/dev/lumify-dev-persistent/opt/jetty/webapps/root.war

cp lumify-web-war-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war /opt/jetty/webapps/root.war 

#Go back to the root lumify folder to build the other dependencies
cd ~/lumify

#Build the other dependencies 
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dsource.skip=true

#copy certain jar+dependencies files created in the folders under lumify/web/plugins/
I would copy the auth-username-only and dev-tools ones.
eg. cp lumify-web-dev-tools-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/lumify/lib

#copy all of the jar + dependencies files in graph-properties-workers to /opt/lumify/lib or hadoop /lumify/libcache

cp ~/lumify-source/graph-property-worker/plugins/translate/target/lumify-gpw-translate-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/lumify/opt
hadoop fs -put /opt/lumify-source/graph-property-worker/plugins/translate/target/lumify-gpw-translate-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /lumify/libcache
```

Hope this helps